# How to print names of the files that are stored in an S3 bucket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to access the name of files stored in a bucket in Amazon S3 but I am having a hard time doing so.

```
import requests
import boto3
from boto3.session import Session

session= Session(aws_access_key_id="access_key", aws_secret_access_key="secret_key")
s3= session.resource('s3')
my_bucket=s3.Bucket("my_bucket")

for s3_file in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(list(s3_file.key))
```

Comment: What do you mean *"hard time"*?

Comment: I am getting an error of Access Denied

Comment: What makes you think you should be allowed access to the bucket? Does the bucket belong to the same account that provided the Access Key and Secret Key? Can you list the bucket using the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket` command?

Comment: Yes, @JohnRotenstein it belongs to the same account.

Comment: What permissions are assigned to the IAM User to allow them to access the bucket?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't address your `Access Denied` error, but it's worth mentioning that it is considered poor security to include the Access Key and Secret Key in your code file.

Instead, you can run the [AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI)](http://aws.amazon.com/cli/) `aws configure` command to store the credentials in a configuration file. Then, your code will automatically find the credentials:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket = s3.Bucket("my-bucket")

for object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    print(object.key)
```

If you are running the code on an Amazon EC2 instance, then it is even easier. Just assign an IAM Role to the instance and the code will automatically receive credentials.

Comment: Yes, I know this way but what if I want to try it by including the Access Key and Secret Key in my code file?

Comment: You can certainly include your Access Key and Secret Key in the code file. It is just recommended not to do this because your code might be stored somewhere (eg GitHub) that someone else can see and use the credentials.